# Deep in the money call option with huge value and no open option buyers before expiry and no money to exercise. How would to sell position

Tags: options

Lets say i bought a 95 delta call options with my whole ira account and all options have huge profit values i want to sell these and there are no buyers for it due to huge value. I dont have additional money to exercise and I cannot put money into IRA how can I sell those positions before expiry.

Comment: This is handled differently by different brokers

Comment: I think this question belongs on the money or personal finance stack exchanges.

Comment: There is always a buyer.  You are just asking for too much.